# Local User Login Script Fedora Linux

Tags: linux, login, script, fedora, local

How do I allow a login script for one user in fedora? ~/.initrc doesn't seem to work, and I tried adding an executable to /etc/init.d but that's for all users (and it didnt work either anyway).

Comment: By login script do you mean something like `.bash_profile` for bash?

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Dennis' answer; this should work for the shell logins (and if not, you'll want to check if the appropriate configuration file is being read/sourced at shell start up).

If you want to run something when a Fedora user logs into X (either Gnome or KDE), then you'll need to do something slightly different. If it's just for your user, you can (when you're running Gnome) use the **System -> Preferences -> Sessions** menu to set any items you want to run.

If you want to do this using a file, I think Gnome sources: ~/.config/autostart . The entries in here should be in FreeDesktop style. For example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Pidgin
Exec=pidgin
Icon=
Comment=
```

I'm not sure how to do this using KDE though...

Comment: I guess that's a virtual +1?

Comment: The best I can do given my starting reputation!

Answer (score 1):

Add a call to your script to the user's `.bash_profile` if the shell is Bash, `.profile` if the shell is `sh` or some others, `.zshrc` if `zsh`, `.cshrc` or `.login` for `csh` or `.tcshrc` if `tcsh`. Note that there is some overlap in these files that I haven't covered in which different shells can use the same startup files.

If you want to have the script start every time a shell is started, rather than just at login, you can use, for Bash for example, `.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

folder:

```
cd ~/.config/autostart
```

from http://cholla.mmto.org/computers/linux/session.html

shell-command:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

the command edits the folder from above - so have a look there if the script does not execute.